# Hyphens are used in words from 0-99 (correction 21-99), but what if a number larger than 99 is a compound adjective before a noun?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, hyphenation, numbers, style-manuals

For example, which of these are correct?

1. The pizza delivery service had three thousand, seven hundred and eighty-two clients.
2. The pizza delivery service had three-thousand-seven-hundred-and-eighty-two clients.

Since example (2) is a compound adjective, where a hyphen is required before a noun, is it therefore still to wrong to use a hyphen for numbers above 99 here?

Comment: Your premise is faulty: cardinal numbers are ***not*** adjectives. They're in their own word-class, one which manifests various syntactic properties distinct from adjectives.  That's about grammar, but what you asked is not. Writing and punctuation are not about grammar.  They're about technology.

Comment: This article says cardinal numbers can be adjectives: "Hyphens join words that work together as a unit to describe something that follows them in the sentence, eg an easy-to-read report. This is called a compound adjective (or compound modifier). Where the description follows the noun, you won’t need the hyphens: the report was easy to read. The same rules apply when numbers are part of the description, and whether the numbers are cardinal (one, two, three …) or ordinal (first, second, third …)."

Comment: Like nouns and participles, numbers can be noun modifiers without being  or becoming adjectives in so doing. So you can have *blind mice* and *completely blind mice*, and you can have *three blind mice*, but you cannot have *❌completely three blind mice*. Why not? Because *three* can never be an adjective, that's why!

Comment: Ok, so which example above is correct and which example is incorrect according to you?

Comment: Sorry, I do not recognize "correctness" as something that can be applied to opinions about writing styles.

Comment: Ok, so which of the above would suit your opinion regarding writing styles?

Comment: IMO, neither of them. The pizza delivery service had 3782 clients, but the precision of the statistic may be pedantic – the pizza delivery service had nearly four thousand clients.

Comment: IMO #1 is the normal way to write a long number. We only hyphenate between 10's and units terms. Note that this includes when they're in the higher parts, e.g. "five hundred twenty-three thousand"

Comment: @WeatherVane There are some contexts where numbers are expected to be spelled out as words. E.g. paper checks have separate fields for the amount in digits and spelled out.

Comment: Even if you consider the cardinal number to be an adjective, we don't treat it as a compound adjective when it's multiple words. The same is true for ordinal numbers: "2026 will be the two hundred fiftieth anniversary of the Declaration of Independence."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a faulty premise.

Comment: NB--It's actually 21-99, except when the number ends in 0.

Comment: "cardinal numbers are not adjectives" is complete nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

*The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010) notes that there are two common ways to handle exact numbers that refer to things other than units of measure: approach #1 is to spell out numbers from one to one hundred but to use numerals for numbers 101 and higher; rule #2 is to spell out numbers from one to ten but to use numerals for numbers 11 and higher.

There is one significant exception to this rule, however—the situation in which the large number occurs at the beginning of a sentence. Chicago (and most other style guides I've seen that address this particular issue) say that in such cases the number should be spelled out in full. Over the course of an extended discussion of "Number beginning a sentence" (section 9.5 in the sixteenth edition), *Chicago* gives three relevant examples of spelled-out large numbers. One of these is a year and two are numbers modifying the noun candidates:

> One hundred ten candidates were accepted.
>
> Nineteen thirty-seven was marked, among other things, by the watershed eleventh edition of Bartlett's *Familiar Quotations*.
>
> One hundred eighty of the 214 candidates had law degrees; ...

A somewhat related instance (discussed in section 9.4 on "Hundreds, thousands, and hundred thousands") involving approximations of very large numbers yields a similar example:

> Some forty-seven thousand persons attended the fair.

One thing evident from these various examples is that Chicago is not inclined to insert "and" before the final term in an exact number: it avoids "one hundred and ten," "nineteen hundred and thirty-seven," and "one hundred and eighty" when given a clear opportunity to include "and" in each instance.

A second thing evident from these examples is that Chicago includes a hyphen only between the tens and ones part of a spelled-out number, regardless of whether the number appears by itself or as a modifier. That is, Chicago implicitly endorses "one hundred ten candidates" (not "one-hundred-ten candidates"), "nineteen thirty-seven" (not nineteen-thirty-seven"), "one hundred eighty" (not one-hundred-eighty"), and "some forty-seven thousand persons" (not "some forty-seven-thousand persons").

On all of these points, Chicago's position reflects the mainstream view of U.S. (and, I believe, British) English style guides.

Comment: ...with the exception that the missing *and* is always included in BrE.